# What is the reason behind different touch target size recommendations between Android and iOS?

Tags: mobile, touch-screen

Touch target size on Android: 48dp

Touch target size on iOS: 44pt

Comment: "dpi" is a nonsensical unit of measurement for a size. https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858?hl=en indicates that you mean 44 "dp".  Also, https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/ says 44 pt, not 44 px.  Note that these are different units.

Comment: My understanding is that 48 dp corresponds to 0.3 inches (1:1 correspondence between "density-independent pixels (dp)" and physical pixels for a 160 dpi screen), and that 44 pt corresponds to ~0.6 inches, so there is a substantial difference in the UI guideline recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason. It's based on their own unpublished independent research.
You should always follow w3 guidelines for accessibility.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size.html
It clearly states to have 44x44 CSS pixels.